# Detect all Android user events including UI "Clicks" & View Transitions

Tags: android, events, logging

I am developing an Android Application and need to log my users "journey" through the application.

The events I wish to log include all user interaction events such as when the user clicks on a button etc, and also each Activity and/or Fragment visited.

I know I can litter my code with my logging logic however there are a number of downsides to this such as:-

- using autoLink "web" and MovementMethod to allow the user to click on
  a web url within a displayed TextView means I have nowhere to add my
  logging code unless I use Spannables or a custom textView.
- Developer human error will result in logging incorrect details or
  missing logging altogether.

What I would like is a single point within the Android framework where I could intercept all UI events and Activity transitions.

I do not wish to create custom widgets to add my logging code.

Is it possible to place my logging code in one Android "hook" to allow me identify which widget was clicked in which Activity/Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to place my logging code in one Android "hook" to allow me identify which widget was clicked in which Activity/Fragment?

No, sorry. Besides, that would be woefully insufficient:

- There are many more UI events than just "clicks" (long-press, swipe, other single-touch and multi-touch gestures, key events)
- Knowing a widget alone is insufficient, as your `TextView` scenario illustrates

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at my issue. What if I employed AspectJ to capture specific events?

Comment: @Hector: I have not looked into aspect-oriented programming on Android, and so I don't know to what extent that is possible -- sorry!